# How to open Form in Add record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form to input records to a table.  I would like it to open on an empty add (New) instead of displaying the first record of the table.  To be used by a Navigation Form which opens the input form from a button.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `acFormAdd` (value = 0) as the optional `DataMode` argument to `OpenForm`.  Access' help describes `acFormAdd` as *"The user can add new records but can't edit existing records."*  And actually, not only does that prevent editing of existing records, they are not even displayed in the form with that option.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmaw_save",,,,acFormAdd
```

If you want to always use the form that way, you can set its Data Entry property to `Yes` (on the Data tab of the form's property sheet).

Comment: +1 This is probably what the OP wants and not simply moving to the New Record

Comment: is there a way to pre-fill some values for the new record?

Comment: See whether [TextBox.DefaultValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.defaultvalue) does everything you need.  If not, submit a new question with details about what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: I've got a program that uses this command, but it still shows the first record instead of the new one.  Is there another setting that might be causing this?

Comment: Do you mean the form is closed and when you then open it with the `acFormAdd` option it displays the first existing record?  I don't know how that can happen.

Answer (score 13):

In the `Form_Load` event use the [`GoToRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212415%28v=office.11%29.aspx) Method of DoCmd and pass in `acNewRec` for the Offset.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent advice.  Thank you both.  I am starting to get the hang of this inaccessible Access language.

Comment: This allows me to navigate to previous records but open to a new record which is the most common reason the form is opened.

Answer (score 9):

On the property sheet, set "Data Entry" to Yes. 
You can turn off navigation buttons too.

Comment: Thank you, I happened to search for this same problem, and your solution worked perfectly, thank you my friend.

Comment: Form properties (Property Sheet) -> Data Tab -> Data Entry -> Yes